# Ratio test (missing proof step): $\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow \infty}\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|<1 \Rightarrow \sum_\limits{k=0}^n a_k$ converges

Tags: convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I'm trying to proof the ratio test for convergence of sum of a sequence:

$l :=\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow \infty}\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| <1 \Rightarrow s_n := \sum_\limits{k=0}^n a_k$ converges absolutely

Currently I'm stuck proving it, and online I've seen other proofs, but I'm interested in this one explicitly, since it's the most intuitive for me:

I'm using the absolute value as a norm for the limit definition.

$\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow \infty}\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|<1 \Leftrightarrow \forall\epsilon>0 \quad \exists n_0>0: \left|\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| - l\right| < \epsilon \quad \forall n\geq n_0$

So we have:

$\forall\epsilon>0 \quad \exists n_0>0: \left|\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| - l\right| < \epsilon \quad \forall n\geq n_0$

MISSING STEP / ASSUMPTION

$\forall\epsilon>0 \quad \exists n_0>0:\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| - l < \epsilon\quad \forall n\geq n_0$

$\forall\epsilon>0 \quad \exists n_0>0:\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| < \epsilon+ l\quad \forall n\geq n_0$

we choose $\epsilon : \epsilon + l < 1$ with its corresponding $n_0$

$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| < \epsilon  + l \quad \forall n>n_0$

And we write:

$\left|a_n\right| = \left|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}\right|\left|\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}\right|...\left|\frac{a_{n_0+1}}{a_{n_0}}\right|\left|a_{n_0}\right| < (e+l)^{n-n_0+1} \left|a_{n_0}\right|$

Therefore:

$ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow \infty} s_n= \sum_\limits{k=0}^\infty \left|a_k\right| = \sum_\limits{k=0}^{n_0-1} \left|a_k\right| + \sum_\limits{k=n_0}^{\infty} \left|a_k\right| < \sum_\limits{k=0}^{n_0-1} \left|a_k\right| + \sum_\limits{k=n_0}^{\infty}(e+l)^{k-n_0+1} \left|a_{n_0}\right| = C < \infty \quad \blacksquare$

I don't understand why I can take the assumption mentioned above? I feel like there's an obvious link I'm missing.

Comment: What would happen if you use $|x|<a \Leftrightarrow -a<x<a$ to $||\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|-l|<\epsilon$?

Comment: You nailed it :) ... so basically I can "remove" the norm because the equivalence would just give me a lower bound. It sounds so trivial and I was clearly overthinking it. In other words $\left|\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| - l\right| < \epsilon \Leftrightarrow -\epsilon < \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| - l < \epsilon \Longrightarrow\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| - l < \epsilon$, correct?... if you want feel free to write the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Set $\epsilon=\frac{1-\ell}2.$ Then for $n\geq N,$ $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<\frac{\ell +1}2=\ell_1<1.$ So this shows that $|a_{N+k}|\leq \ell_1^k a_N,$ and $$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}a_N \ell_1^{n-N}$$ converges.

Comment: Thomas, that's a nice idea for choosing $\epsilon$ if I want to get concrete with an upper bound for the limit. I will leave the selection of a specific $\epsilon$ open though, since it is not relevant for proving the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was why

$\forall\epsilon>0 \quad \exists n_0>0: \left|\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| - l\right| < \epsilon \quad \forall n\geq n_0$

would imply the following:

$\forall\epsilon>0 \quad \exists n_0>0:\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| < \epsilon+ l\quad \forall n\geq n_0$

The key is the rule $|x|<a\Leftrightarrow -a<x<a$ for $a>0$. If we apply the rule to $\left|\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| - l\right| < \epsilon$, we have

$\displaystyle -\epsilon < \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| - l < \epsilon\tag*{}$

This implies

$\displaystyle \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| - l<\epsilon \tag*{}$

or

$\displaystyle \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| <\epsilon+l \tag*{}$

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=l<1.$$Take $\varepsilon>0$ such that $l+\varepsilon<1$. Since $\varepsilon>0$,$$(\exists n_0\in\Bbb N)(\forall n\in\Bbb N):n\geqslant n_0\implies\left|\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|-l\right|<\varepsilon.$$ But then, $$n\geqslant n_0\implies\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<l+\varepsilon.$$So, if $n\geqslant n_0$,$$|a_n|\leqslant\left|a_{n_0}\right|(l+\varepsilon)^{n-n_0}.$$

Comment: Thank you, I corrected that mistake. Also my notation was mixing up $k$ and $n$. But the question is about why I can remove the norm safely?

Comment: Because $a-b\leqslant|a-b|$, and therefore$$|a-b|\leqslant\varepsilon\implies a-b\leqslant\varepsilon.$$Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. Quite a trivial think which I was overthinking.

Comment: Hi Jose, I had a user that answered before. Also the answer I was looking for was about the inequality. Your answer corrected a mistake I had, but it wasn't exactly the point of my answer. I'm still very thankful for you effort and as soon as I have the reputation to do it (I only recently joined) I will upvote your answer.